# How to detect position liquidation at FTX exchange

Tags: c#

I do integration with FTX exchange, connect to it using REST API via JKorf's libraries. Call methods of FTXClient class in the library like GetUserTradesAsync().
How to find out that a position(s) was liquidated by the exchange ? Which API endpoint will return me this information (datetime, liquidation price etc) ? After the information was downloaded in a table I calculate position amounts at every trade using SP in sql server (using sum window function). Currently, since I don't know that position was liquidated, my position amount/side gets incorrect (eq new position was opened and from some trade I should start summing again from zero).

I looked in here https://docs.ftx.com/#rest-api but did not find anything on it, maybe it was called differently.

Thank you,

Slava

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We're going to need more information

Answer (score 0):

I believe the information you require is here: https://docs.ftx.com/?csharp#get-order-history.

From the "GET /orders/history?market={market}" response you can use to keep track of your open orders. Then use "GET /fills?market={market}" to keep track of your filled orders. I would use the order history to get the start times of your orders and the filled orders to get your close times along with prices and other info.